# QuickFIX/J: Type 'quickfix/field/HaltReason' is not assignable to 'quickfix/IntField'

Tags: quickfixj

**Summary**

We have a quickfix client which receives SecurityDefiniton and SecurityDefinitionUpdateReport messages. These are bulk datas. When we logged to the server they send messages around 8000. At the end they're sending SecurityStatus message. In this part we are getting an exception.

Fix protocol version: FIX50SP2 with FIXT1.1

Quickfix message dependency

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
       <artifactId>quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Quickfix Core

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
       <artifactId>quickfixj-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception we received;

```
Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    quickfix/fix50sp2/SecurityStatus.get(Lquickfix/field/HaltReason;)Lquickfix/field/HaltReason; @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'quickfix/field/HaltReason' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'quickfix/IntField'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'quickfix/fix50sp2/SecurityStatus', 'quickfix/field/HaltReason' }
    stack: { 'quickfix/fix50sp2/SecurityStatus', 'quickfix/field/HaltReason' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b600 1557 2bb0

        at quickfix.fix50sp2.MessageFactory.create(MessageFactory.java:297)
        at foo.bar.data.plugin.fix.api.MessageFactory.MessageFactorySp2.create(MessageFactorySp2.java:93)
        at quickfix.MessageUtils.parse(MessageUtils.java:145)
        at quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler.messageReceived(AbstractIoHandler.java:131)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:858)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
        at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:398)
        at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:234)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:535)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:703)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:659)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:648)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1120)
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We couldn't get SecurityStatus fix message. The problem we thought was about datadictionary. As a field HaltReason is a CharField

```
public class HaltReason extends CharField {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617L;
    public static final int FIELD = 327;
    public static final char NEWS_DISSEMINATION = 'D';
    public static final char ORDER_INFLUX = 'E';
    public static final char ORDER_IMBALANCE = 'I';
    public static final char ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION = 'M';
    public static final char NEWS_PENDING = 'P';
    public static final char EQUIPMENT_CHANGEOVER = 'X';
```

When we look FIX50SP2 default datadictionary halt reason field is INT.

```
<field number="327" name="HaltReasonInt" type="INT">
<value enum="0" description="NEWS_DISSEMINATION"/>
<value enum="1" description="ORDER_INFLUX"/>
<value enum="2" description="ORDER_IMBALANCE"/>
<value enum="3" description="ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION"/>
<value enum="4" description="NEWS_PENDING"/>
<value enum="5" description="EQUIPMENT_CHANGEOVER"/>
</field>
```

We tried convert dictionary field to HaltReasonChar and the type CHAR but it didn't work. Did you ever get an exception like this?

Here's the security status message which I received.

```
8=FIXT.1.19=00017835=f49=BI_TEST56=LIABR34=589857=TRTK152=20220208-20:07:15.9281180=R1181=28513331350=285133255=T2-ON48=3762690422=M336=148325=N60=20220208-20:07:15.92810=245
```

Comment: Why do you add `core` dependency in a different version than the `message` dependency? Could you try using both at the same version (preferably the most current one)? I assume that the field is looked up in the wrong JAR since also `core` contains the field classes.

Comment: I updated the dependencies to 2.3.1 but the same error exists. @ChristophJohn

Comment: I added the SecurityStatus fix message to the question.

Comment: I think you need to compile against that version as well. But am not completely sure.

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: Did you do a complete and clean rebuild of your application with the new dependencies?

Comment: Of course, i updated the dependencies and reloaded them. After that i rebuild the project and deployed the test environment.

Comment: What does your runtime environment look like? Is it a plain java application or are you using QFJ in Spring Boot or Camel or some other environment? A workaround could be to access the field as String field. That should work in any case.

Comment: It's plain java. How can i access the field as String? That field is INT in QuickfixJ core.

Comment: `message.getString(int field)`

Comment: As you now We have classes with extend MessageCracker. They have methods "onMessage" to get "Cracked" messages. The method for SecurityStatus onMessage is empty in my case. I'm not doing anything with that message. So probably the problem is with Message cracker. It tries to map quickfix message to SecurityStatus but it cannot assign the HaltReason because it can't convert message field to the integer. So I can't edit the core files.

Comment: In the stack trace there is a `foo.bar.data.plugin.fix.api.MessageFactory.MessageFactorySp2.create`. Could you try just by using the QFJ built-in factories?

Comment: Hi Christoph, MessageFactory2 is copy of DefaultMessageFactory with FIX50SP2 support. Old version of DefaultMessageFactory was not supporting FIX50SP2. Thats why we used in that way.

Comment: OK but I think that has been solved some versions ago so that you can remove your custom factory.

Comment: I changed to DefaultMessageFactory now i have lots of unsupported message type. 35=pr and 35=f. I have both message in my datadictionary for FIX50SP2. Quickfixj has SecurityStatus(msgtype=f) but doesn't have 35=pr PriceReference. I'm not sending a request to server to get those messages. They're automaticly sending me. How can i ignore those messages? @ChristophJohn

Comment: So your original problem is solved?  Then you should create a new question

Comment: Thank you. You can post as an answer.

Comment: @esterial - when you post the FIX message itself, please include the field delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the `HaltReason` field (`tag 327`) is included in your status message. Is it an optional or required field for the `SecurityStatus` message type? You can control that in your data dictionary definition.

The dictionary for FIX50SP2.xml I have indicates this field is *not* required, but yours could be different.

Be careful of broker-supplied dictionaries; they are frequently wrong or outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked fine for me: report is of type quickfix.fix44.SecurityStatus

```
try {

                    response.setHaltReason(report.getString(327));
        
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error...
            }
```